Automatically create a polygon of non-white borders from WTMS imagery
I was wondering how could you create a (multi) polygon representing the borders of non-white areas in a non-worldwide, online WTMS imagery automatically?

The WTMS in question: https://data.geopf.fr/tms/1.0.0/ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS.ORTHO-EXPRESS.2024/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpeg
To preview it: https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/carte?l0=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS.ORTHO-EXPRESS.2024::GEOPORTAIL:OGC:WMTS(1)&permalink=yes

That's a picture of the data not the data so there isn't much you can do with it, except look at it.

Digitize it manually, it is done in maybe an hour.
